# What are some important female names who participated in the first human genome sequencing project?

Tags: 20th-century, 21st-century

Specifically, females involved in the human sequencing project, from between 1990 and early 2000s (I'm especially interested in medical doctors, but tech experts or of other branches of science are very much appreciated as well). Thank you to whoever answers.

Comment: List question.  How will you select an authoritative answer?

Comment: Whoever brings me more names of women whose work was more influential to the human genome project more, as opposed to taking a more passive role. Also I think I will be favoring medical doctors in case there are several incredibly good answers. I really hope I haven't broken any rules by asking this question.

Comment: Have you done any research? Eg checking the authors df the main papers?